# Using numpy to Obtain Submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do the following with `numpy` (python newbie here)

### Create a zeroed matrix of the rigth dimensions

```
num_rows = 80
num_cols = 23
A = numpy.zeros(shape=(num_rows, num_cols))
```

### Operate on the matrix

```
k = 5
numpy.transpose(A)
U,s,V = linalg.svd(A)
```

### Extract sub-matrix

```
 sk = s[0:(k-1), 0:(k-1)]
```

#### Results on error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tdm2svd.py", line 40, in <module>
sk = s[0:(k-1), 0:(k-1)]
IndexError: too many indices
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the docstring for `numpy.linalg.svd`.  You'll see that `s` is a *1d* array holding the singular values.  Also, `numpy.transpose` does not change an array in-place, so the line `numpy.transpose(A)` has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to answer your question s is only a 1d array ...  (even if you did actually transpose it ... which you did not)

```
>>> u,s,v = linalg.svd(A)
>>> s
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>>
```

for selecting a submatrix
I think this does what you want ... there may be a better way

```
>>> rows = range(10,15)
>>> cols = range(5,8)
>>> A[rows][:,cols]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

or probably better

```
>>> A[15:32, 2:7]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```